# Properly validate JSON Path in Java

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea

I am looking for the good Java way to validate a JSON Path. However, it seems that everyone has its own definition of a "valid JSON Path". I'll explain myself.

In this post, I will consider the three following paths :

1. `field.innerField`
2. `field.inner field`
3. `field/innerField`

I want to help my users to clearly understand if their JSON Paths are valid or not, and why. To do so, I want to validate the given paths, and if it is not valid, send them a link to the JSON Path documentation (https://jsonpath.com/)

I use 3 distinct "tools" to test the validation of these paths.

- In my code, I use the `compile` function found in this class: `com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath`
- I am using IntelliJ as an IDE, and when I use a String as a JsonPath, IntelliJ (somehow) check that my String is a valid JsonPath and add a red underline if the JsonPath is not valid
- I validate my JsonPath online on https://jsonpath.com/

So for the first JSON Path it is okay, every tool agrees, the path is valid.

For the second path :

- The `compile` function of JsonPath throws the following error `InvalidPathException: Use bracket notion ['my prop'] if your property contains blank characters`
- In the same way, IntelliJ tell me that the path is not valid (`(', '.', '..', <*> or '[' expected` on the space character)
- The online tool on jsonpath.com handle properly this path and retrieves the wanted elements

I am ok with my code throwing an error and expecting a more correct path (`field.['inner field']`), but my users will get lost by seeing that their paths work properly on the online editor.

For the third path :

- The `compile` function of JsonPath do not throw any exception (but, the "real" JSON Path in this case is `$.['field/innerField']`, probably not was the user wanted.
- However, IntelliJ tell me that the path is not valid (`'(', '.', '..', <*> or '[' expected, got '/'` on the `/` character)
- The online editor on jsonpath.com has the same behavior as the `compile` function

If my users specify this path, they probably want in reality to use this JSON Path : `$.field.innerField`. So I would like to be able to detect if I am in this case (which IntelliJ editor somehow manage to do) and link them the documentation.

So in the end, I am looking for a validation method that will throw an exception in case 2 and 3, and an online documentation/editor that will behave accordingly. Does theses exists ? (And why everyone has his own way to do JSON Path :'( )